# One touchable opacity doesn't press when another touchable opacity is pressed

Tags: javascript, react-native, touchableopacity, onpress

I was making a program in React native in which there are two buttons which when pressed will increase a tap counter.
The problem is when one button is pressed the other won't respond and doesn't increase the counter. The button is made with Touchableopacity and the action is done by onPress.

```
<View style = {{flex:1,flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'center'}}>
            <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.button}
            onPress = {() => this.start() }
            >
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                Tap
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.button}
            onPress = {() => this.start() }>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                Tap
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Can you try passing the keys to your buttons? It's kinda hard for react to know what exactly you're pressing otherwise and it can lead to bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `onTouchStart` instead of `onPress`.

So change:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.start()}>
```

To:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onTouchStart={() => this.start()}>
```

The reason you want to to this is because while one button is still being pressed, the `onPress` action on another button won't fire until you stop pressing the original button.

Answer (score 0):

The problem i resolved by using  and onTouchStart instead of  and onPress

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of React Native the previous posters were using but "onTouchStart" is only available on View components not on Touchable Opacity.

Wrapping my touchable in a view mimics onPress behavior very well

```
<View onTouchStart={myEventHandler}>
  <TouchableOpacity>
    <Text>My Touchable Button</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```